# Visual Studio RSS feed URL

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rss, feed

I have Visual Studio 2012 and the startup page shows news from 2013 despite being in 2016.
The url is
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=84795&clcid=42C
I have tried other clcid like 42D, 42A but couldn't find an up-to-date rss feed
Does anyone know the url for the latest news ?

Comment: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=84795&clcid=419 gives recent news in Russian somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=84795&clcid=409 
 This rss link above works 100% this is what am using on my Visual Studio 2010.
And i do get all feed up till Nov 2018.

Comment: This redirects to https://vsstartpage.blob.core.windows.net/news/vs in case anyone wants to use the direct URL. It might change though so it's probably better to use the fwlink one, I just can't stand how ugly that one is so I'll take my changes with the nice one.

Answer (score 3):

After a search, I found this url:
http://sxp.microsoft.com/feeds/msdntn/VisualStudioNews
It looks like an up-to-date feed.

Comment: this is no longer available. the feed from [@CRUSIFIXSSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303722/767425)'s answer is the current feed.